# Issue with OpenGL texture rendering

Tags: opengl, java, graphics, lwjgl, slick

I am developing a game in Java using LWJGL2 and Slick, and I am encountering an issue when rendering a graphic.
Instead of filling the quad with the texture, it appears to be partly repeating it. The image is simply a white box, but this is how it is appearing when the program is run:
[image: How the texture appears]
I am loading the image using Slick:

```
this.texture = TextureLoader.getTexture("PNG", ResourceLoader.getResourceAsStream("Res\\image.png"));
```

and I am using this code to render it:

```
texture.bind();
GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
            GL11.glTexCoord2f(0,0);
            GL11.glVertex2f(position.x,position.y);
            GL11.glTexCoord2f(1,0);
            GL11.glVertex2f(position.x + size.x,position.y);
            GL11.glTexCoord2f(1,1);
            GL11.glVertex2f(position.x + size.x,position.y + size.y);
            GL11.glTexCoord2f(0,1);
            GL11.glVertex2f(position.x,position.y + size.y);
    GL11.glEnd();
```

If I remove all the code for textures and just render a coloured quad, it displays as expected.
Could you please point me in the right direction as to where I am going wrong?

Comment: You shouldn't use legacy OpenGL versions (GL1), it is deprecated and some drivers don't support it

Comment: So this is a problem with my drivers as opposed to my code? Also, what should I be using instead?

Comment: @Bálint: There are no OpenGL drivers that don't support legacy OpenGL. Even MacOSX and Linux open-source drivers still support legacy OpenGL.

Comment: @NicolBolas that’s what I would have thought - I’m pretty sure games such as Minecraft use legacy OpenGL, and they work fine on my PC

Comment: @Nicol Tell that to mine. I just tried it and got the "Legacy OpenGL not supported message"

Comment: @Bálint: 1) What is "mine", exactly? 2) Exactly what did you try?

Comment: I don't believe for a second that any sensible driver will drop support for Legacy OpenGL anytime soon. There's a TONS of software in active use (and games) that use OpenGL 1.x. Blender was one of them up till recently.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I'm aware that this is not exactly the answer to your question, but it can lead you to the solution of your problem.

As [@Bálint](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/67769/b%C3%A1lint) mentioned in the comments section, you shouldn't use legacy OpenGL anymore, which are all version before OpenGL 3.0. Although the OpenGL 2.0 was the first version to switch from [Fixed Function Pipeline](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Fixed_Function_Pipeline) to [Programmable Pipeline](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Rendering_Pipeline_Overview), it was the OpenGL 3.0, that marked Fixed Function Pipeline and most of the previous OpenGL functions and constants as [deprecated](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Deprecation), thus, really switching into the modern standard graphical API.

I strongly encourage you then, to also switch from the old OpenGL into the modern one.
There are a lot of good tutorials on the internet regarding modern OpenGL.

One of them, that I find really interesting and essential is [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VS8wlS9hF8E&list=PLRIWtICgwaX0u7Rf9zkZhLoLuZVfUksDP) YouTube series created by **ThinMatrix**. He introduces all of the modern OpenGL aspects in the easy and transparent way and he uses Java and LWJGL. (And he also of course shows how to use textures! :) )

I also recommend [these tutorials](https://learnopengl.com/Introduction). Although they are written using C++, the idea of the OpenGL constructs remains the same regardless the language.

Modern OpenGL might look a little bit overwhelmingly at the beginning, compering to legacy OpenGL, but as you follow the learning process, you'll find it fun and - most importantly - you will find a lot of advantages in using Modern OpenGL over the old one.

Also, if you'd like to read more about differences in OpenGL versions and about OpenGL itself, I recommend these links:

1. https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki
2. https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Legacy_OpenGL
3. https://glumpy.github.io/modern-gl.html

I hope it helps you somehow and that the community won't eat me because of not directly answering your question.

Good luck!

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with the question. Depending on what the OP wants to do this might actually be detrimental. Can't beat 10 LoC to get a textured quad on the screen.

Comment: The answer to the question is glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP); glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP);

Comment: @JBeurer the answer box is just a bit lower on the page, if you'd like to share your recommendation with some explanation about how it solves the problem.